# Page size and block size

Tags: caching, virtual-memory

We all know in address translation from virtual address to physical address, the lower bits are used as page offset so they are not translated. Instead they stay the same. This means that the page size in virtual memory is the same as the physical memory.

We also know that when moving a block from memory into the cache using modulo method, the size of the block in both sides is the same.

My question is, does this mean that the page size in virtual memory should be the same as the block size in cache.

Answer (score 5):

No, cache lines are one size (eg: 16, 32, or 64bytes), virtual pages are another independent size (often 4K).

Reading an entire 4K page into the cache would be too slow and make the cache ineffective for most use cases so CPUs use smaller cache lines.

Comment: why would I move 4K from the disk to memory when needed, while all size I need in the cache is 64bytes. I don't understand what would I do with the rest of the 4k I didn't use.

Comment: Because you can only mark entire pages as accessible or inaccessible.
The reason why pages are much larger is due to the size of the page-table that would be required for smaller pages. It takes over 4MB to map 4GB of 4KB pages, if pages were 64bytes it would take over 256MB of page table to map the entire 4GB of ram on a 32bit CPU. There's also a high overhead for reading 1 sector from HDD while reading multiple consecutive sectors has much lower overhead after the first, making it efficient to read, say, 4KB at once.

Comment: What if my block size is 128MB and I want to do 64KB pages? does that even make sense?